# How can I use logarithms to get the opposite of power?

Tags: combinations, logarithm

I was never good at maths in school and I realized that I actually need the opposite of **pow(base, exponent)** functions which powers some number by some factor like 2 ^ 4 = 16

Searching for answers I found that logarithm **log()** should be the opposite of power.
Now, I've found that to write e.g. *"log 2 of 32"* would in code look like `log(32) / log(2)`... but how do you translate this following problem into logarithm?

I'm going to write a quick C program to print index table where all alphabetical characters are going to be printed assigned to each index **starting from 0 to 26 ^ DIGITS**.

Assuming DIGITS are set to 1, table will only be of size 26 (the length of alphabet from A to Z) in format index[0] = A, index[1] = B, ... ... index[25] = Z.
**The count of DIGITS gives 26 ^ DIGITS combinations**.

Now, I have this code already written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned int letterToIndex(char c);
char indexToLetter(unsigned int index);

int main(void)
{

    printf("Printing Index table:\n\n");

    const int DIGITS = 2;
    const int ALPHABSIZE = 26;

    int currentIdx = 0; // current index

    const int endIndex = pow(ALPHABSIZE, DIGITS);
    
    // this should be 
    //double bit5 = log(32) / log(2);
    //printf("log(32) / log(2) AKA bit^5 should be: %f", bit5);
        
    while (currentIdx < endIndex)
    {
        
        printf("index[%i] = ", currentIdx);
        
        /*for (int i = 0; i < DIGITS; ++i)
        {
            //float logarithm = log( (currentIdx / ALPHABSIZE) % ALPHABSIZE ) / log(DIGITS);
            float logarithm = log( currentIdx % ALPHABSIZE ) / log(DIGITS);

            printf("%c", indexToLetter( (int) logarithm ));
        }*/
        
        
        // letter 
        //unsigned int idxLetter = letterToIndex(i) * ALPHABSIZE + letterToIndex(i+1);
        
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // I have an obvious pattern here vv
        
        // here I print only 2 digits hard-coded
        // prints the 1st digit
        printf("%c", indexToLetter( (currentIdx / ALPHABSIZE) % ALPHABSIZE ));
        // prints the 2nd digit
        printf("%c", indexToLetter( currentIdx % ALPHABSIZE ));
        
        // obvious pattern ^^
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        
        printf("\n");
        currentIdx++;
    }

    
    // if DIGITS are only 1 sized:
    // index[0] = A
    // index[1] = B
    // index[2] = C
    // index[3] = D
    // index[4] = E
    // ... ... ...
    // index[25] = Z

    // DIGITS having size of 2:
    // index[0] = AA
    // index[25] = AZ
    // index[26] = BA   =   index[ 1 * 26 + 0  ] = index[26]
    // index[30] = BE   =   index[ 1 * 26 + 4 ] = index[30]
    // ... ... ...
    // index[107] = ED =    index[ 4 * 26 + 3 ] = index[107]
 
    return 0;
}

// maps the ASCII range from 'A' = 0 to 'Z' = 25
unsigned int letterToIndex(char c)
{
    return toupper(c) - 'A';
}

// get any letter from 0 to 25: from 'A' to 'Z'
char indexToLetter(unsigned int index)
{
    return toupper(index + 65);
}
```

I've commented out the **for loop** inside the main (inside the **while** block), and this time hardcoded to printf currentIdx's first digit and then its second digit at each iteration in the while loop.

But it strikes me like it's asking for a logarithm... How can I automate this in the for loop? Instead of having two **printf** lines, I'm pretty much convinced these two lines:

```
printf("%c", indexToLetter( (currentIdx / ALPHABSIZE) % ALPHABSIZE ));
printf("%c", indexToLetter( currentIdx % ALPHABSIZE ));
```

could be put into one line with the right (maybe logarithm?) solution. If it was `DIGITS` size 1, only the 2nd line would apply. `DIGITS` of size 3 requires opposite of power to 3. It's clearly **power** to `DIGITS`.

But what to make out of this pattern in a loop? Let's say `const int DIGITS` (that's currently set to 2) could be changed to be higher. How to make it dynamic so that it'll combine the alphabet for every digit?

Comment: The iteration is handling the logarithm. You really just need to use modulo and process right to left.

Comment: You can start with `pow(alphabsize, digits - 1)` and use integer division. On each loop you successively reduce that divisor by a factor of `alphabsize` down to 1. This lets you output left to right. Either way logarithms are implied by the looping but not necessary to compute directly. And the correct term is "combinations" rather than "permutations".

Comment: You already know the length and thus the largest power required to get calculate the highest-order digit. Logarithms would come into play if you wanted to go in reverse order and determine the (maximum) length based on a known table size.

Comment: Thank you! I already updated (edited) the hashtag from "permutation" to "combinations", and this code worked for me:
 `for (int i = pow(ALPHABSIZE, DIGITS-1); i >= 1; i = i / ALPHABSIZE ){
         int theIndex = ((currentIdx / i) % ALPHABSIZE);
         printf("%c", indexToLetter(theIndex));
}`
I want to mark your comments as the solution... (I suppose the moderators do that?)

Comment: No, you would mark a solution if I had written an answer. In the index calculation that modulo step should be unnecessary btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with `pow(ALPHABSIZE, DIGITS - 1)` and use integer division to get each place value/table index. On each loop you successively reduce by a factor of `ALPHABSIZE` down to 1. This lets you output left to right.

Logarithms are not necessary to compute here. To compute an integer logarithm you could nevertheless just count the number of passes through a `while/for` loop in the same fashion.